# Solving a recurrence function with two variables

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

My goal is to learn how to solve recurrence functions consisting of two variables.

For example, I want to find how to solve the following function which I have found in a paper:

$$
T(d,a) = 
     \begin{cases}
       0 &\quad\text{if } d = a\\
       \sum_{i=1}^{a} T_{drop}(d,i) + T\left(d-i,a-i+1\right) &\quad \text{if } d > a \\
     \end{cases}
$$

where

$T_{drop}(d,i) = \frac{\left( d - i +1 \right) \left( d - i + 2\right)}{2} $

The paper mentions that the generating function is

$$
G(x,y) = \left(1 -y(1=x)\right)^{-1} \cdot \sum_{0<i<j} T_{drop}(j,i)x^iy^j
$$

The resulting closed form of $T(d,a)$ is

$$
T(d,a) = \sum_{i=0}^{a-1} \sum_{j=i}^{d-a+i-1} {j \choose i} \cdot T_{drop} (d-j,1) 
$$

I have just started learning on how to use generating functions to solve recurrences with 1 variable but I am having some trouble with this one. I am not sure how to approach this problem. Any help would be appreciated.